# Constraint definition language

Tags: python-3.x, configuration, data-annotations, constraint-programming

I need to design a language which enforces constrained based on definitions like below. The listing below is an actual annotation configuration for [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/configuration.html#additional-details). I am tasked with designing a language for our in-house tool for similar purposes. I am planning to write the parser in python too.

```
[entities]
Drug
DrugClass
Procedure
Therapy
AE
SAE
Disease

[relations]
Equiv   Arg1:<ENTITY>, Arg2:<ENTITY>, <REL-TYPE>:symmetric-transitive

BelongsTo   Arg1:Drug         , Arg2:DrugClass
BelongsTo   Arg1:AE           , Arg2:AE
BelongsTo   Arg1:AE           , Arg2:SAE
BelongsTo   Arg1:SAE          , Arg2:SAE
BelongsTo   Arg1:SAE          , Arg2:AE
BelongsTo   Arg1:Disease      , Arg2:Disease
BelongsTo   Arg1:Drug         , Arg2:Therapy
BelongsTo   Arg1:Procedure    , Arg2:Therapy
BelongsTo   Arg1:Surgery      , Arg2:Therapy

<CAUSE>=Drug|DrugClass|Therapy|Procedure
<EV>=AE|SAE

AssociatedWith      Arg1:<CAUSE>    , Arg2:<EV>
NotAssociatedWith   Arg1:<CAUSE>    , Arg2:<EV>

Causes          Arg1:<CAUSE>    , Arg2:<EV>
NotCauses       Arg1:<CAUSE>    , Arg2:<EV>

HasEffect       Arg1:<CAUSE>    , Arg2:Disease
HasNoEffect     Arg1:<CAUSE>    , Arg2:Disease

<OVERLAP>   Arg1:<ANY>, Arg2:<ANY>, <OVL-TYPE>:<ANY>
```

What I have in mind is the following.

```
[entities]
# subtyping entities which is already present in brat
Entity
  Trigger
    Drug
    DrugClass
    Procedure
    Therapy
  Effect
    AE
    SAE
    Disease

[relations]
# Any subtype of Trigger can be Associated with any subtype of Effect except Disease    
AssociatedWith  Arg1:Trigger    , Arg2:Effect.except(Disease)
NotAssociatedWith   Arg1:Trigger    , Arg2:Effect.except(Disease)

Causes      Arg1:Trigger    , Arg2:Effect.except(Disease)
NotCauses       Arg1:Trigger    , Arg2:Effect.except(Disease)

HasEffect       Arg1:Trigger    , Arg2:Disease
HasNoEffect     Arg1:Trigger    , Arg2:Disease

# Equiv relation can exist between Drug and Drug,
# DrugClass and DrugClass and so on,
# but not between different subtypes Drug and AE
Equiv   Arg1:Entity*          , Arg2: Entity*      

BelongsTo   Arg1:Entity*          , Arg2: Entity*      
BelongsTo   Arg1:Drug         , Arg2:Therapy
BelongsTo   Arg1:Procedure        , Arg2:Therapy
BelongsTo   Arg1:Surgery          , Arg2:Therapy

<OVERLAP>   Arg1:<ANY>, Arg2:<ANY>, <OVL-TYPE>:<ANY>
```

Is there already a language which can do this. I have looked into Prolog which seems like an overkill. I think I am looking for a language which can handle grouping of objecst and granular addressing such that the constraints can be specified concisely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its easier to think about, how will these definitions look like *in memory after parsing* - and then work backwards. One easy way to parse is by thinking of each line as a "method call" - e.g. "BelongsTo Arg1:Drug" can be seen as an implicit "this.BelongsTo" method call on a ParserContext object. So you basically "eval" the file with a ParserContext class, and each line in the file "silently" calls methods on the base class, slowly building up the in-memory . When the last line is complete, the in-memory definition is also complete.

In Ruby, one doesn't need parantheses around methods, and "this." is implied (as in most other languages). So, what you consider as DSL/language is just plain code in Ruby.

Let's take a simplistic Parser class.

```
class Context
  def new
    # initialize some vars
    this.entities = {}
  end

  def Entity(name, ...args)
    # save to 
    self.entities[name] = ...args
  end

  def BelongsTo(entity, ...args)
    # process belongs to with the entity
  end

  ... every DSL feature is a language method ...
  ... if you want to "zoom-in" or focus on an entity, use blocks
```

And let's take the following DSL...

```
Entity "Arg1"
BelongsTo "Arg2"
```

And this simple reader:

```
ctx = Context.new
ctx.instance_eval File.read "my dsl file"
```

So the DSL file is just evaluated with "this" set to the context object, and each line in the DSL are just plain method calls. Gemfile in Ruby, Routes file in Rails, many ORM definitions, etc - use this trick all the time. What *looks* like DSL is just pretty code. with As a simplistic example on Ruby - https://github.com/rdsubhas/ruby-blocks/blob/master/Mapping - you'd see that although it looks like a DSL, its actually just code, and there is actually *no parser* involved to parse that code. The language itself parses it.

This is not only for Ruby, each language has its own "eval" tricks. I believe same can be done with nodejs as well (jasmine/cucumber tests).

Hope that answers your query. To summarize:

- See how it will look like in memory *after* parsing
- Work backwards for a DSL
- Use the language parser

Side note: The DSL you showed looks complicated enough that its not easily usable by business/product people. Looks like its intended for developers or power-users. So don't put self constraints on the DSL, like it must have brackets, or it must not have double quotes or that kind of stuff. When this is meant for power users, usage of quotes or brackets will cease to matter. Choose one that has least effort for you.